# AllowHtml does not work with model first - "potentially dangerous request"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, xss, ef-model-first

I am using MVC with model first. I used `[ValidateInput(false)]` on my controller which accepts a rich text input. This worked fine. Now I found the following post which allows me to use `[AllowHtml]` which I would prefer ([post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10112094/allowhtml-attribute-on-entityframework-class)).

```
[MetadataType(typeof(YourEntityMetadata))]
public partial class YourEntityClass
{            
}   

public class YourEntityMetadata
{
    [AllowHtml]
    public string YourPropertyWithHtml { get; set; }
}
```

I tried this but it did not work. For test reasons, I added `AllowHtml` directly onto the property in the auto-generated model, which also did not work. In both cases I got the same error "Potentially dangerous request..."

The input in question is a simple rich text `<p> lorem <\p>` from CKEditor.
The controller calls a separate function which does the actual writing to access to the database, and the access to the model first ModelContainer.

Is there something in the auto-generation which might prevent the `[AllowHtml]` to work. Is it a problem that the controller does not directly access or create the entity but passes the string to another function which creates the entity and saves it to the database?

EDIT

I disabled the filters which check for the XSRF token. I have the request validation mode set:

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```

I stripped down the controller method to:

```
public int SaveBlock(string blockCont)
{
    var testt = new ViewTest() { BlockContent = blockCont };
    return 0;
}
```

with a simple view model:

```
    public class ViewTest
{
    [AllowHtml]
    public string BlockContent { get; set; }
}
```

and still the request is marked with a "potentially dangerous" error.

Comment: `[AllowHtml]` will work fine assuming its applied to the correct property.

Comment: You should not put anything on the auto generated class code. Infact you really do not need this property on your entity class. You should create a view model to transfer data from your view to action method and apply this attribute on the relevant property on that.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4866070/6268935) and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/82170/6268935).

Comment: Hi Arman, it is too late now to fully look into this but the first link might be really helpful. I indeed access the `Request` in a `Filter` to check for the XSRF Token. This might trigger the validation before the `[AllowHtml]`. I will check this tomorrow.

Comment: What is the `public int SaveBlock(string blockCont)` method? You need to show the method your posting to which should be `public ActionResult SaveBlock(YourEntityMetadata model)`

Comment: Base on your edit, the controller method needs to be `public ActionResult SaveBlock(ViewTest model)` - you cannot just use a `string` - your `[AllowHtml]` is applied to your view model property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read a bit more into the issue with the useful comments in mind. My confusion was that I thought the data annotations are applied when data is written into the model not when it is accepted in the controller method.

So of course my approach to send a string to the controller and to hope that it is validated when I actually write it into the model was wrong. Perhaps I wanted a bit too much.

For my approach, in which I want to separate out my data models from the controller as much as possible (using a repository), I guess the only way forward would be a view model of the input sent to the controller. However, in my case I suppose I will stick to encoding the few non-html string inputs, to let only the one html input through to the database.